# Errors during Window resize for Viewer that isn't visible

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I am hosting an Autodesk Viewer inside a bootstrap div, and find that when the tab is not active, hiding the Viewer, there are errors thrown when the window is resized.

I would like avoid this by tearing down the Viewer and preventing it from handling any resize events when the tab is deactivated.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The below code appears to work for me:
'viewerInstance.impl.unloadCurrentModel();
viewerInstance.tearDown();
viewerInstance.uninitialize();'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct, attach an handler to your tab hidden depending on your code and do something like below:

```
if (this.viewer) {

  if(this.viewer.impl.selector) {

    this.viewer.tearDown()
    this.viewer.finish()
    this.viewer = null
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like finish() is new to viewer v2.13.  I've updated my viewer and will call .finish().  Thank you Philippe.

Comment: It's been there for a while, prior to 2.13. Make sure to call tearDown also, it may cause memory leaks otherwise.

Comment: I noticed that my viewer temporarily flashes a black background before starting to render the 3d scene on build 2.13.  Does 2.13 have another initialization step that I am missing?